# How can we attract more people who participated on this site in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm following [the proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) and I'm seeing the number of visits per days and % of answered questions dropping.

As someone who can mainly only have a pure meta role. I'm feeling at the best place to ask such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this crucial? We are now in open beta, so the key to attracting more visits and users is having quality answers to questions. It doesn't necessarily need to be A51 committers.

Everyone that committed to the A51 proposal has already gotten an email about it; if they haven't visited the site yet, they probably won't do so until they're interested enough.

The focus should be on interesting questions and quality answers that people want to know more about, so that we can pick up search engine traffic.

Comment: When I asked the question we weren't. And I was feeling the site could be closed like [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61961/computer-graphics-programming).

Comment: According to the proposal page, public beta commenced at `2015-06-08 18:34:29Z`, and your question was asked at `2015-06-09 17:42:36Z`. Maybe I misunderstood. _shrugs_